# css font face not working at all

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

In one of my website  I have used `Ænigma Scrawl 4 BRK font(as it is showing in my photoshop font family box)`. Now I want the same font in my page. So for that I just went to [FontSquiirel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) site for generate css style. There I got my css file with the font with different extensions like `.svg, .ttf, .woff`. I just paste all the fonts in my folder then I used the same converted css in my style.css file. The generated css was like this

```
   font-family: 'nigma_scrawl_4_brkregular';
    src: url('aescrawl-webfont.eot');
    src: url('aescrawl-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('aescrawl-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('aescrawl-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('aescrawl-webfont.svg#nigma_scrawl_4_brkregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
```

But after all that my font style has not been changed. I am checking in both firefox and chrome. I have cleared all the cache and cookies from my browser. Can someone kindly tell me what is the wrong here? Any help and suggestions will be appreciable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'nigma_scrawl_4_brkregular';
.
.
.
.
font-style: normal;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@font-face{
    font-family : "myCustomFont";
    src:url(aescrawl-webfont.ttf);
}

body{
    font-family:"myCustomFont", Arial;
}
```